# Storing certain sub-sequences in for-loop ( or maybe recursion )

Tags: c#, algorithm, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays, subsequence

the task is as follows:

1) Input = sequence of "n" numbers ( n - positive, numbers - no limitations)

2) Objective: Extract the longest non-decreasing sub-sequence. If two ore more sub-sequences have the same length - print the leftmost.

Example: input = 7 3 5 8 -1 6 7, output = 3 5 6 7

Now while bashing my head on it for a whole day, I encountered two major problems. The first is to write an algorithm that stores all possible non-decreasing sub-sequences from the input sequence. The second is to come up with an optimal way to measure all sub-sequences and print out the leftmost longest. Here is where I am currently at:

```
using System;

class LongestNonDecreasingSequence
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] chars = input.Split(' ');
        int[] numbers = new int[input.Length];
        int n = chars.Length;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(chars[i]);
        }
        int[,] matrix = new int[n, n];
        for(int column = 0; column < n; column++)
        {
            for(int row = column, rowMatrix = 0; row < n; row++)
            {
                if(numbers[column] <= numbers[row])
                {
                    matrix[column, rowMatrix] = numbers[row];
                    rowMatrix++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int column = 0; column < n; column++)
        {
            for(int row = 1; row < n; row++)
            {
                if(matrix[column, row] < matrix[column, row - 1] && /* ?Condition */)
                {
                    /* Remove ?elements */
                }
                /* ?Remove rows, cointaining zero value */
            }
        }
        int[] matrixLengths = new int[n];
        for(int column = 0; column < n; column++)
        {
            matrixLengths[column] = matrix.GetLength(1);
        }   
    }
}
```

I have a 2D array storing each sub-sequence in a new column. In our example - 7 3 5 8 -1 6 7; in column 0 we store 7, column 1 - 7 8, column 2 - 3 5 8 6 7, column 3 - 5 8 6 7, column 4 - 8, column 5 - -1 6 7, column 6 - 6 7, column 7 - 7;

Now problem 1) In every sub-sequence remove the numbers, not fitting the condition. In our case: column 2 - 3 5 6 7, column 3 - 5 6 7;

Now problem 2) Compare all columns (1 - 7) by Array.Length and get the highest.

I still can't figure out the algorithm for problem 1. For problem 2 I only need to know how can I measure the length of each separate column in my 2D array. From what I've been reading for the past hours, maybe I have to use jagged array, instead of 2D. Would it be easier to get each column's length then? Defining every next jagged array (array of each column)in the for-loop would be trickier, but I think I can do it using string to hold my numbers and then using '.Split' to assign value to the array.

I hope I expressed myself clearly enough. If that is not the case, please inform me, so I can specify. Any suggestions and information for both problems are very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence ?

Comment: This is a known problem solved using Dynamic Programing, Check Longest increasing subsequence.